# In Profile:Edit edit page add text with Matrix

Tags: safecracker, matrix, profile-edit

i've a big challenge. I'm trying to replicate this form from behance in my edit profile page made with Profile:Edit add-on by mightybigrobot. Users can add manually their own social URL selecting from a fixed dropdown list.

I would something like that attached
http://www.behance.net/portfolio/profile/info

In the Member profile fieldgroup i add a Matrix fieldtype, in the first column i choose PT Dropdown, and in second i choose text.

But now i don't know how i can display in the front-end form in members edit page.

Somebody can help me?

Thank you Guys

Comment: What have you tried? What problems have you encountered? The more specific you can be the better we can answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The edit tag for Profile:Edit is a descendant of the SafeCracker module and so you can use all of Safecracker's parameters and variables. If there's ever anything missing in the Profile:edit docs you can normally find it in the Safecracker docs within the EE user guide.

For fieldtypes that have complex markup like Matrix, you need to use the `field:my_field_name` variable.

Docs: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#field-my-field-name

So the (very) basic template code would be:

```
{exp:profile:edit
    safecracker_head="yes"
}
    {field:matrix_field}
{/exp:profile:edit}
```

You'll probably need to include more parameters than that but I've include the `safecracker_head` one to show that it is required for Matrix because it'll load in the required Javascript. You'll also need to include the `include_jquery` parameter and set it to either yes or no depending on whether you're already loading it on the page.

More docs:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#include-jquery
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#safecracker-head

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with profile:edit, but it's like going to be something like:

```
{exp:profile:edit}
{matrix_field}
{pt_dropdown}
{/matrix_field}
{/exp:profile:edit}
```

Replace matrix_field and pt_dropdown with your field and column short names, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing the only difference is my dropdown in the matrix field is a playa field which is displayed via safecracker.

First, create another embed template and place your PT Dropdown code in it so you would have something like this:

```
<select name="mymatrixfield[selections][]" id="mymatrixfield">
    <option value="mymatrixfield">Add Additional Website</option>
    {exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" channel="portfolio"}
    <option value="{entry_id}">{title}</option>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</select>
```

> You would replace the my matrixfield with your matrix field name and
>   change the channel name.

Next, add embed the template into your profile:edit template and you should be good to go e.g.

```
{embed="includes/.templatename" selected="{mymatrixfield:child_ids}"}
```

> Again you would replace mymatrixfield with your matrix field name and
>   .templatename with your corresponding template name.